# How to install english.pickle for nltk on an off line Linux machine

Tags: python, linux, offline, nltk, pickle

I am trying to run nltk on a SUSE Linux box which cannot be connected to the internet.

I have successfully installed nltk and it runs but when I submit

```
>>> tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
```

I get this error:

> LookupError:
>        **********************************************************************
>   Resource 'tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle' not
>   found. Please use the NLTK
>   Downloader to obtain the resource:

I cannot use the downloader since I can't connect the box to the internet.

Does anyone how I can install the necessary packages?

Answer (score 4):

Data is downloaded to the `nltk_data` directory. Where that is differs from one system to another, but you can find out by doing the following:

```
import nltk
print nltk.data.find('.')
```

`english.pickle` should be in a subfolder of `<nltk_data>/taggers/`. The easiest way to put it there is to use the downloader on a machine that has internet access, then copy it over and put it in the same subfolder. There's only one version of `english.pickle`, and you can download it on a Windows box, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

The downloader stores the files in a particular folder. I imagine it's possible to download on an online machine and copy the files to the equivalent location on your offline machine. On my machine, it downloads to `/usr/local/lib/nltk_data`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - if I was to do this on a windows machine would the downloaded files work on the Linux box?

Comment: Sorry, i just saw your comment. I don't know, but I imagine the data should be cross-platform (except possibly for line endings).

Answer (score 1):

For reference purposes (as of 2017), punkt tokenizers are found at this link in GitHub:

https://github.com/nltk/nltk_data/blob/gh-pages/packages/tokenizers/punkt.zip

You should be able to download from a non-airgapped machine, and move it over on a flash drive.